# Error when trying to log in to instaloader python

Tags: python, instaloader

When I try to login to instaloader through Terminal, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/instaloader", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('instaloader==2.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'instaloader')())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instaloader.py", line 1160, in main
    loader.download_profiles(args.profile, args.login.lower() if args.login is not None else None, args.password,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instaloader.py", line 983, in download_profiles
    self.interactive_login(username)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instaloader.py", line 959, in interactive_login
    self.login(username, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instaloader.py", line 516, in login
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 328, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

I have not edited or changed anything in the scripts it is showing, so I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

L = Instaloader()
username = "your username"
password = "your password"
L.login(username, password)

profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, username)
posts_sorted_by_likes = sorted(profile.get_posts(), key=lambda post: post.likes,reverse=True)
for post in posts_sorted_by_likes:
    if post.is_video:
        L.download_post(post, username)
```

Properly arrange the code and it will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**They have explicitly the solution in their webpage and it worked for me**: https://instaloader.github.io/troubleshooting.html#login-error.
I am gonna copy it exactly :

**Login error**

> Instaloader’s login should work fine, both with and without
> Two-Factor-Authentication. It also supports handling the checkpoint
> challenge, issued when Instagram suspects authentication activity on
> your account, by pointing the user to an URL to be opened in a
> browser.
>
> Nevertheless, in Issue #92, Issue #615, Issue #1150 and Issue #1217,
> users reported problems with logging in. We recommend to always keep
> the session file which Instaloader creates when using --login. If a
> session file is present, --login does not make use of the
> failure-prone login procedure. Also, session files usually do not
> expire.
>
> If you do not have a session file present, you may use the following
> script (Example 615_import_firefox_session.py) to workaround login
> problems by importing the session cookies from Firefox and bypassing
> Instaloader’s login and so still use Instaloader’s logged-in
> functionality.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from glob import glob
from os.path import expanduser
from platform import system
from sqlite3 import OperationalError, connect

try:
    from instaloader import ConnectionException, Instaloader
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    raise SystemExit("Instaloader not found.\n  pip install [--user] instaloader")


def get_cookiefile():
    default_cookiefile = {
        "Windows": "~/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*/cookies.sqlite",
        "Darwin": "~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/*/cookies.sqlite",
    }.get(system(), "~/.mozilla/firefox/*/cookies.sqlite")
    cookiefiles = glob(expanduser(default_cookiefile))
    if not cookiefiles:
        raise SystemExit("No Firefox cookies.sqlite file found. Use -c COOKIEFILE.")
    return cookiefiles[0]


def import_session(cookiefile, sessionfile):
    print("Using cookies from {}.".format(cookiefile))
    conn = connect(f"file:{cookiefile}?immutable=1", uri=True)
    try:
        cookie_data = conn.execute(
            "SELECT name, value FROM moz_cookies WHERE baseDomain='instagram.com'"
        )
    except OperationalError:
        cookie_data = conn.execute(
            "SELECT name, value FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%instagram.com'"
        )
    instaloader = Instaloader(max_connection_attempts=1)
    instaloader.context._session.cookies.update(cookie_data)
    username = instaloader.test_login()
    if not username:
        raise SystemExit("Not logged in. Are you logged in successfully in Firefox?")
    print("Imported session cookie for {}.".format(username))
    instaloader.context.username = username
    instaloader.save_session_to_file(sessionfile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-c", "--cookiefile")
    p.add_argument("-f", "--sessionfile")
    args = p.parse_args()
    try:
        import_session(args.cookiefile or get_cookiefile(), args.sessionfile)
    except (ConnectionException, OperationalError) as e:
        raise SystemExit("Cookie import failed: {}".format(e))
```

> To use this script,
>
> 1. Download the script: Example 615_import_firefox_session.py,
> 2. Login to Instagram in Firefox,
> 3. Execute the snippet, e.g. with python 615_import_firefox_session.py,
> 4. Then, instaloader -l USERNAME should work fine.
>
> This script also supports specifying a cookie file path, which may be
> useful if you use multiple Firefox profiles or if your operating
> system has the directory structure differently set up. Also, you can
> specify an alternative session file path.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to login through python script them this snippet of code will get you there

```py
from instaloader import Instaloader
USERNAME = "YOUR USERNAME"
PASSWORD = "YOUR PASSWORD"

L = Instaloader()
L.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```